# How to deploy web site (not web app) on windows azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

I want to deploy a website (not web app) on windows azure
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/get-started/
this link guide about deployment of web apps not website

I have already created website using Visual Studio 2010 and want to deploy same using visual studio

Comment: See here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-create-websites/#deployoptions

Comment: You can use the publish profiles/web deploy like mentioned in the article you linked to to push code to Azure. Are you seeing any specific errors?

Comment: See my answer below. Those updates include Website project support as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebDeploy or FTP based publishing method as described below:

[How to use Web Deploy and FTP publishing from VS 2010 against Windows Azure Websites (Without using Azure SDK)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/4ffc50e0-56ca-43c1-8c5c-a3171daf5c34)

Answer (score 0):

You can also publish using Git, as detailed in [this article](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-git/)

The advantage of using Git for deployment is the continuous deployment aspect via BitBucket, Github or CodePlex. Create your Git repository in Bitbucket (for example - allows for private repositories, so you can use it even if your site is not Open Source, unlike Github), link it to your Azure account and then push the code to Bitbucket. Azure will then automatically deploy the site for you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you install the tools from the link you provided, you will get the same experience for Website project as you have for Web App Project.

Follow these steps:

1. Download Web publish updates
2. Import your Azure Websites with publish profile
3. Click publish

FYI you can also get the updates from the ASP.NET 2012.2 updates http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/02/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-update.aspx. These will also be included in VS Update 2 once it is released.